# Store every year directly from the date of entry of a user

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I need to store every year directly from the date of entry of a user to the business the problem is that every time I add a year is inserted between the day and month.

```
var yearOnCompany = moment(user.fecha_ingreso_empresa, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
var dateStart = moment(user.fecha_ingreso_empresa).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
console.log(dateStart);
//03-12-2009
var f = parseInt(yearOnCompany);
var yearsOfWork = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= f; i++)
{
    dateStart = moment(dateStart, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'years').calendar();
    yearsOfWork.push(dateStart);
}
console.log(yearsOfWork);
```

Result of this:

```
0:"12/03/2010"
1:"03/12/2011"
2:"12/03/2012"
3:"03/12/2013"
4:"12/03/2014"
5:"03/12/2015"
6:"12/03/2016"
7:"03/12/2017"
```

Comment: how about `yearsOfWork.push(dateStart.format("DD-MM-YYYY"))`

Comment: or `dateStart = moment(dateStart, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'years').format("DD-MM-YYYY");`

Comment: yeah! this work thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subtle error! According to the moment docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ `.calendar()` uses a default date format, possibly using the locale of the environment, if none is provided, so here it looks like it's defaulting to `MM/DD/YYYY`, rather than the desired `DD/MM/YYYY`. So on the first iteration `dateStart` is converted to `12/03/2010` with the month and day swapped. Then on the next iteration it's converted back to `DD-MM-YYYY`, again with the day and month swapped, then when passed to `.calendar()` again the day and month swap again giving the correct format again.

A potential bug is that you're changing `dateStart` from a string to a moment object, so I'd rewrite the code like this:

```
var dateStart = moment(user.fecha_ingreso_empresa).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
var f = parseInt(yearOnCompany);
var yearsOfWork = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= f; i++)
{
    dateStart.add(1, 'years');
    yearsOfWork.push(dateStart.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
}
console.log(yearsOfWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the problem with the format, correct me if I am wrong.
Please try this.

```
 for(var i = 1; i <= f; i++)
 {
   dateStart  = moment(dateStart , "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'years');
   yearsOfWork.push(dateStart.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
 }
```